# Software to add text to image

Tags: windows, open-source, images, text-processing, clipboard

I am looking for a software that allows me to add text to a picture and to easily select and customize the text. It should have these requirements:

- Easy to add image from clipboard. I usually copy images from google by right-click on it and select `Copy Image` (Firefox). I don't want to download the image.
- Add text quickly, and be able to re-select it
- **Be able to change the text outline**. The lack of this feature in most light-weighted softwares is the reason I ask this question.

[image]

- Easy to copy image after edited to clipboard. Being able to <kbd>Ctrl-A</kbd> then <kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd> is favorable.
- Free, or better, open source.

I use Windows, but it would be nicer if it's available for Linux. Another option to consider is light-weight.

Comment: Doesn't MS Paint do all these??

Comment: I can't figure out how to customize the text border, unfortunately

Comment: what do you mean by adding text border? Could you tell about it clearly?

Comment: It may be usually called as *text outline*. I have added an example in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My current software is **Pinta**. It doesn't require me to install any plugin to modify the outline of the text. Moreover, the default feature of Pinta even has more function than the plugin of Paint.NET.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If you need a software to draw texts on pictures I recommend you the free yet powerful Image Editor [Gimp](https://www.gimp.org/downloads/) in which you can draw texts on your pictures beside its many other features. You can download it for Windows, OSX or Linux.

Tutorial for adding outline effect on text [can be found here](http://www.gimpology.com/submission/view/how_to_outline_text).

If you ever need an online free tool for putting text (captions) in various formats (including outline effect) on your pictures I recommend [AddText.com](http://addtext.com/) or [Picfont.com](http://picfont.com/).

Comment: Gimp is powerful image editor but it's heavy. All the websites require me either to download the image from Google before upload it or download the final result. If I have to choose one between the two, I would use Picfont.com

Answer (score 1):

Paint.NET with the plugin [Outline Object](http://paint.net.amihotornot.com.au/features/effects/plugins/object/outline/) will satisfy the requirements. It is an FOSS and available only in Windows.

Pinta is a similar FOSS to Paint.NET, but available to Linux and Mac as well.

Comment: Paint.NET is not open source (though some of the older versions were).

Comment: Your link is not working anymore. I just tried installing the outline plugin for Paint.NET and it doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by Ooker - "My current software is Pinta.", Pinta is a great software for you. I'd also like to recommend you **Inkscape**. It's a great program that saves text as an vector image. **Krita** is another great software. But it's not that relevant. Hope this helps you.

Comment: https://youtu.be/QpS69s0BiaQ

Comment: http://klikit.pbworks.com/f/1240247266/Three-D%20Text-3.png